# ADB2C custom policy for Sign In only. How to add KMSI and control the password rest link

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Im setting up a custom policy so there is a unique policy for

1. Sign up
2. Sign In
3. Reset password

(I need it like this as each unique custom template will have its own tracking/analytics code.)

For the sign in policy, I am currently using the selfAsserted content definition rather than the unifiedssp one, so that I can hide any chance of signups from here. This works fine - however, I cant see how I can add the built in KMSI?

(I don't mind switching back to the unifiedssp to enable KMSI, but how do I disable account creation from this flow?)

Secondly, if I use the unifiedssp, the forgot password link doesn't point to my custom password reset policy - it tries to do this in the unified way. Is it possible to set a custom target for this rather than handling the error in my application and forcing a redirect?

If I stick to the selfAsserted display instead, is there an preferred way to add the forgot password link (rather than just hard coding it in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raj,

Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#metadata

you can disable the signup link by setting the showSignUpLink metadata to false.

```
<Metadata>
<Item Key="setting.showSignupLink">IpAddress</Item>
</Metadata>
```

In regards to the embedded password reset, this has been a pain point for the b2c developers for a while now.

Here is a sample that embeds the password reset into an IDP option. You can find details on that here: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset.

Please let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't solve the password reset link url being wrong so doesn't give me a fully workable solution.

Comment: Sorry, working on several things. Allow me a few minutes to update my answer.

Comment: Awesome! In terms of structuring extensions such as this, would it be best to move the UserJourney to the Base or Extension, or better to keep it in the RP as it is quite specific?

Comment: Also when you are in the password view, the UI still presents a cancel button which in this case is valid I think. However, clicking it will send you back into the error flow again from what I can tell. Is there any way to improve this?

Comment: true, but there is another setting that you can use, setting.showCancelButton should be set to false if you want to hide the cancel button.

Comment: Sure, aware of that setting now, but it could still leave the user in a state where they are stuck. Its definitely nicer than before though as user is less likely to cancel in reality and we I get a load less errors in my application.

Comment: In addition, you can set <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkLocation">none</Item> to hide the default forgot password link so you require less hacking on the UI code.